# DIV and IFRAME overlapping backgrounds don't follow z-index rules

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

I have a problem with absolutely positioned elements that lose image-based background when they overlap an iframe:

http://pix.am/LM9e.png

Dark stuff is a youtube iframe, red and green boxes are absolutely positioned divs above it (z-index:100 vs iframe z-index: 50). Red box background disappears where it overlaps the iframe, green box background is solid color and is okay in Firefox.

Firefox 7, Win XP 32 (doesn't occur on Macs).

Latest Chrome/Safari are even worse, they hide both boxes behind the iframe.

Anyone met this bug before and willing to share a fix?

Comment: Have you tried to recreate this with something else then youtube video in the iframe? Maybe it's the flash issue, since it doesn't occur on mac.

Comment: This very well may be flash, I agree, but it has to remain that way — with flash in the iframe.

Comment: AFAIK, flash doesn't respect z-indexing well.